# Export part of MySQL table depending on corresponding values in two columns

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I'm saving my tables to CSV files using

```
mysql -B -uNAME -pPASSWORD NameOfDatabase -e "SELECT * FROM relevantData WHERE StartTime = '2018-06-17 21:00:00' order by EndTime;" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > DataFor2018-06-17-21:00:00.csv`
```

which works fine to save every row where `StartTime = xx`, but in this table `StartTime` can have multiple `EndTime`. I want to create one file for each combination of `StartTime`-`EndTime`combo.

I know I can use `SELECT * FROM relevantData WHERE StartTime = '2018-06-17 21:00:00' And EndTime ='2018-06-17 22:00:00'` for each `EndTime` but I'm going to do this quite a few times so I need a way to find list all `EndTime` values corresponding to each `StartTime`. Some way to automate this (Find each `EndTime` and maybe even save them) would obviously be preferable but it might be out of my league since I'm not very experienced.

**Update:**
I've found that

```
SELECT DISTINCT EndTime from RelevantData Where StartTime = '2018-06-17 21:00:00';
```

works to get all endtimes for a starttime. But if it's possible I'd love to get some help to run this for many different times. I think I need at least 100 different files so doing this manually will be quite monotonous.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just run this query and copy the results: `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('mysql -B -uNAME -p ...AND EndTime = \'', EndTime, '\'...') FROM...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this - you first generate the desired SQL queries (one query for each unique EndTime) and then execute them one by one.

Note: the code was not tested - just to give you an idea

```
start='2018-06-17 21:00:00'

mysql -B -uNAME -pPASSWORD NameOfDatabase -e "SELECT CONCAT(\"SELECT * FROM relevantData WHERE StartTime = '$start' AND EndTime = '\",EndTime,\"'\") FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EndTime FROM RelevantData WHERE StartTime = '$start') AS tmp" | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;' > tmp.sql

seq=1
while read -u 10 query || [[ -n $query ]]
do
  mysql -B -uNAME -pPASSWORD NameOfDatabase -e "$query" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > "DataFor${start}_${seq}.csv"`
(( seq++ ))
done 10<tmp.sql
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much! Is there a way to store the `EndTime` time to be used instead of ${seq} in the name? Since the end times can differ quite much it would be very useful to see the interval instead of the sequence. I'm trying to figure this out ATM but I don't quite understand this so no luck yet. Thanks again!

Comment: You can add the EndTime in the CONCAT - e.g. `SELECT CONCAT(EndTime,"_", ...` and then when you read the resulting file line by line - take the first 20 characters from the current line as EndTime and send the rest symbols (after the 20-th) to MySQL.